# Accessing a web application's static resources

Tags: java, web-applications, maven-2, wicket

I've just built a very simple Java web application using the [Wicked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wicket) framework. The current layout of the project is:

```
src/
    main/
        java/
            net/myapp/
                Homepage.java
                Homepage.html
        reources/
            scripts/
                script.js
```

In the `Homepage.html` file I am trying to load the JavaScript file:

```
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

I deployed the application, but the browser doesn't find the JavaScript file.

The [WAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29) file is being packaged using the maven-war-plugin. I looked into the WAR file, and I see the following layout:

```
WEB-INF/
    classes/
        net/myapp/
            Homepage.class
            Homepage.html
        scripts/
            script.js
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web-related resources should be placed in `src/main/webapp`

Comment: yeah this is correct, see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: @Sean it says that src/main/webapp should contain the Web application sources. Does that mean the html/java or the javascript files? (btw, This was the structure created by the wicket archetype) What about images? do those go in the /src/main/resources?

Comment: @Mario Duarte - images also go to /webapp. Unless you want to have a custom way of serving the resources (for example via a special servlet).

Answer (score 3):

Your directory structure should be:

```
WEB-INF/
    classes/
        net/myapp/
            Homepage.class
            Homepage.html
        net/myapp/scripts/
            script.js
```

and your markup should be:

```
<wicket:link><script src="scripts/script.js"></script></wicket:link>
```

Comment: This works too if you want your scripts embedded with your java packages.

Comment: Who wants to have non-program code inside the class directories?
In my opinion, the public javascript files should not be placed in the private server code.

Answer (score 3):

Resource sitting behind WEB-INF folder are not publicly available. If Homepage.class forwards to the Homepage.html, file you should be seeing that fine. But in the HTML page you have your reference to the javascript file, which is not publicly available. You need to move the scripts outside of the WEB-INF. The structure should look like

```
WEB-INF /
     classes /
     net/myapp/
          Homepage.class
          Homepage.html
scripts/
      scripts.js
```

This way a refernce in the html file to

```
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

will work properly. When the HTML page is rendered on the user side, they will make the call back to get the JavaScript resource. At this point, the file needs to be visible.

An update of your build script, or app layout should take care of this for you.

**Edit:** See Bozho's answer, it will fix the build for Maven. see [This link for Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers are correct in general, they don't quite take Wicket into account. With Wicket, you **can** have resources on the classpath, and in some cases they are better than a static file.

You can use `Application.mountSharedResource()` to assign a url to a shared resource, which can come from anywhere, your classpath included.

Answer (score -1):

Spelling resources without the s?

```
reources/
```